# BFO Java Report Generator - Print Even Number of Pages

Tags: freemarker, netsuite, bfo

Is there a way with BFO Report Generator templates to force printing an even number of pages?

We currently are using the Report Generator to bulk print a set of reports and have set the printing option to double-sided. When a report has an odd number of pages the next report starts on the back of the previous print - we'd like the next report to start on a fresh page.

Have tried inserting the following at the bottom of the template (before closing `body` tag) but to no avail:

```
<#if (totalpages?number%2 != 0)><div style="page-after-break: right"></div></#if>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you check in the raw output of that `div` gets in? Because the FreeMarker part looks OK (that parenthesis is redundant BTW).

Comment: The first problem I'm having is that `totalpages` isn't being recognised.

Comment: With what error message?

Answer (score 1):

The [BFO FAQ](http://bfo.com/faq.jsp#3.21) explains how to do this:

> **How do I force a page to begin on an odd or even page?**
>
> You can set this is in the `<pbr>` tag - eg. `<pbr page-break-before="odd">` which means only do a page break if the next page is odd. You can also do `<pbr page-break-before="even">`, which means only do a page break if the next page is even.